# Return a generated image object only when it is ready

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have the following JS function which returns an Image object (randomly drawn) which I can place somewhere in the page.

```
function shipIt(w,h) {

    var img = new Image();
    // This function generates the image through a little complex (messy)  random logic
    img.src = wing(w, h / 2, 2, 4).toDataURL('image/png');

    // This section creates a mirror of the above image and sews em together
    var cvs1 = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx1 = cvs1.getContext('2d');

    cvs1.width = w;
    cvs1.height = h;
  var img1 =new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
    ctx1.drawImage(img, 0, h / 2);
    ctx1.save();
    ctx1.translate(0, h / 2);
    ctx1.scale(1, -1);
    ctx1.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    ctx1.restore();
  console.log('loaded!!');
  img1.src = cvs1.toDataURL('image/png');
  console.log('url taken!!');
    };
  console.log('trying to load!!');



  console.log('will return now!!');
    // This is not returning the img correctly
    return img1;

    }
```

I am not seeing the image correctly when I try placing this into an img element, as the return statement executes even before the image load.

Is there any way to counter this?

Comment: Assign to `.onload` before assigning the `.src`. If the `.src` loads fast enough the `.onload` may never be executed.

Comment: Also, that will return the image, possibly before the img1 is loaded, as you mentioned. The function you assign `ImageInstance.onload` is Asynchronous. In your case you probably just want to affect the DOM, so do that instead of returning anything. Do it inside the function assigned to `ImageInstance.onload = function(){ /* in here */ }`, before assigning the `ImageInstance.src = 'yourImgURL.png'`. I create my own Promise code when working with canvas and a lot of images.